# Why use only static classes to test rest endpoints while using Jersey Test?

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey, jersey-test-framework

I have been using JerseyTest framework to test endpoints in my application. I am fairly new to this.

I studied a few other test cases written by other developers of my company. They do not test the Resource class directly but rather write a static class within the test case and test the static class.

Even in the Jersey Guide, I notice examples of only testing static classes.

I do not understand the purpose of writing test cases like this because my goal was to test my resource class so what will we achieve if we write a static class and test that?

**Class to be tested is below**

```
class SomeController {

@Post
@path("/someResponse")
private SomeResponseObject doSomeWork(@NotNull SomeObjectParameter parameter) {
   //Code for processing request and prepares the response object
   return someResponseObject;
}
}
```

**But the class tested within the unit test class**

```
public class SomeControllerTest extends JerseyTest {

@Path("/path")
public static class ControllerResource {
    @Post
    public SomeResponseObject getSomeWork() {
        //Prepared SomeResponseObject
        return someResponseObject;
    }
}

@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(ControllerResource.class);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    SomeResponseObject response = target("hello").request().post(SomeResponseObject.class);
    //Do assertions
}
}
```

Now if you notice the Configure method, the class that is added is the static class that is created within the test class rather than the class to be tested which is SomeController.class

What is the point of writing the unit test here if we are not testing the SomeController class? What are we trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you please show some code?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy Added the Code. Can you please tell if my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a unit test used with Jersey test framework which contain already an embedded container so trying to test the ressource itself doesn't really need to instanciate the controller class , its members will be accessed anyway.

Comment: But I am not testing SomeController.class in this test case right. Instead am only testing ControllerResource which is not even the class to be tested.

Comment: i dont really get your comment, ControllerRessource is in SomeController

Answer (score 0):

It's because Jersey can't create it if it's not `static`. You are passing a class to the `ResourceConfig`, so you are telling Jersey to create an instance of it. If you just register it as an instance, then it doesn't need to be static, since Jersey will not need to create the instance.

```
 return new ResourceConfig()
     .register(new ControllerResource());
```

I don't think that not being able to create it is something that is specific to Jersey. It's more related to Java. All the other frameworks that I can think of that I've used inner classes for, it's the same thing, like Spring and Jackson. Inner classes need to be static for the framework to create the instance.

As an aside though, there is never really any reason to have the resource as an inner class of the test. I post many examples using Jersey Test Framework, and the only reason I use inner resource classes in the test is the make the example self-contained and runnable as-is. Normally your resource class would be in a separate file, where there is no need for static.

Comment: so you are telling me that I can use "SomeController.class" in resourceConfig and register it as "new SomeController()" within ResourceConfig.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to if the SomeController is in it's own file. Read the last part of my answer. I don't really get why your question is about the ControllerResource, bu then you are asking about the SomeController. How do they fit together with your question?

Comment: Ok I think I am confusing everyone. Let me try again. SomeController is existing in src/main/java/com.package/somecontroller.java
I want to test the above someController.java

My test case is in src/test/com.package/SomeControllerTest.
Now usually for a test case, we test the class in the main package. But in this case we are creating a static class and testing it. I have noticed many people doing this. What will we achieve if we do not test SomeController.java in the main package.

Comment: Read the last paragraph of my answer. You don't need the inner class. The only time you will ever see this is in a self-contained **example**.